# How to get column index in onCustomDrawCell event in DevExpress QuantumGrid (VCL)

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

In my application, I need co draw some grid columns (not completely rows) in different colors.
How can I get current columt id, from TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo variable?

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to change colors, you don't need owner-drawing. Use cxStyles.

Answer (score 6):

You can use AViewInfo.Item.Index.

Alternatively you could assign a different OnCustomDrawCell handler to each column instead of a single one to the view. Then there is no need to differentiate the columns.

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
procedure TFrmBestellingen.grdRequestDBTableCustomDrawCell(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;AViewInfo:   
  TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
var
  varValue: Variant;
begin
  inherited;
  // Which column must i paint: Paint on column <TcxGridDbColumn>
  if (AViewInfo.Item.Index = <TcxGridDbColumn>.Index) then
  begin
    // Get Value to compare if it is 100
    varValue:=AViewInfo.GridRecord.Values[<TcxGridDbColumn>.Index];
    if (Not VarIsNull(varValue)) and
       (varValue=100) then
    begin
      ACanvas.Font.Style:= [fsBold];
      ACanvas.Brush.Color:= clSilver;
    end;
  end;
end;
```